# How to change Botton tab bar Background Color in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` Package. But I don't know how to change background color of the tab bar. Here is my Code.

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from "./TabScreen/Home";
import Category from "./TabScreen/Category";
import Search from "./TabScreen/Search";
import Profile from "./TabScreen/Profile";
import Colors from "../../../Style_Sheet/Colors";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs =()=>{
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarPosition="bottom" barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0000' }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerTitle:"Explore",headerTintColor:Colors.white,}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={Category} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
export default Tabs;
```

I am adding under then Tab.Navigator tag but it's not working.

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version **6** you have to add screenOptions like this in Tab.Navigator

```js
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
  }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
<Tab.Navigator 
screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
      }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

not working then change the Theme Color,
The below code will work when assigning border-radius and can't change the background color
[image]

1.`import {NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';`

2.

```
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: '#fff',
  },
};
```

3. `<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000000',
      tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 14, textTransform: 'capitalize', fontFamily:'Poppins-Regular'},
      tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA' },
      tabBarUnderlineStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    }}
    // tabBar={NavRenderer}
    >

    // ....Your screens

</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).